# Bootstrap4 navbar not collapsed on desktop page load - fine in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

URL TO TEST SITE: [enter link description here](http://marvel-adventures.com/user/user_profileGet.php)

I have just attempted to upgrade to bootstrap 4 (alpha 6)

It seems that I am having the opposite issue of most people, in that my .navbar is not collapsed as expected on the initial page load in desktop view. Rather it appears as a horizontal list which pushes the .navbar element to take up about a third of the desktop view. However the .navbar will not uncollapse in mobile view.

Here is the navbar html render:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/" class="navbar-brand">Marvel Adventures</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/aboutus.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/guides/starter_guide.php" title="A users guide to MA">Guides</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/surveys/index.php" title="The entrance to our Survey App">Surveys</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/__demo/" title="Monkee's test file directory">Monkee</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/characters/index.php" title="Characters, Applications, Faceclaims, Want Ads, and more!">Characters</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/__demo/contact.php" title="A demo for building postback forms">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/user_profileGet.php#" title="modal version of contact form">Modal</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://marvel-adventures.com/user/login.php" title="Login to site" target="_blank">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done the following so far in an attempt to resolve the issue:

1. used chrome to inspect the navbar.
2. checked to make sure all stylesheets are loading.
3. checked that all javascript are loading
4. check that jQuery is loading
   a. googled for possible solutions.
   b. checked stack over flow for possible solutions.

I've just upgraded to bootstrap 4. I have looked on stackOverflow and googled in attempts to find a resolve to my issue, but i have as yet to find one.

Comment: I placed your code into Bootply and set it to use Bootstrap 4 / jQuery 2.x and everything is functioning w/o issue: https://www.bootply.com/pA1BCBOU5J  I did correct a few classes though and remove the `.icon-bar` so things were more easily visible.

Comment: Thank you very much I will go and look at that now and after lunch I will try to test and implement on my local system. I'm very new to all of this stuff and just doing dump things to learn. Again thank you Robert.

Comment: @Alex Howansky I see Alex made an edit to my question, but i can't tell what he edited. Is there a way to ask him or find out what he changed so that i can learn how to ask better / more properly formatted questions?

Comment: You can click on the "edited x mins ago" link to see the changes. I didn't touch the question itself, just removed inappropriate tags.

Comment: Also, if you tag a user (like you did with the @) in your comment, then they get an inbox alert. That's the typical manner to direct a question/comment at a specific person.

Comment: Thank you for the help, everything appears to be working now and I'm not sure what happened. Perhaps my system wasn't releasing old cached css sheets maybe?